# Prepared statements in ipn-script

Tags: php, security, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a question which relates to ipn-security,
do i need to use prepared statements in an ipn-script?

I mean the script is only called by paypal, so is there any need to?

or can i just use:

```
$query1 = "INSERT ...";

if ($mysqli->query($query1)) { etc..
```

or do i have to escape posted variables from paypal:

```
$mc_gross = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
```

or its okay to do:

```
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
```

variables coming from paypal, so is there any need to this as well?

greetings!

Comment: Well, it depends what you're planning to write to the database, and how you're passing variables to `$query1`.

Comment: writing strings into database, and i already did: htmlspecialchars(),trim(), stripslashes()..so?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you **don't** want to use prepared statements? Better to be safe than sorry.